# How can a Nautilus script be run for an empty directory?

Tags: nautilus, scripts, directory, context-menu

I have a Nautilus script that can create multiple directories at once using `mkdir` with the option `-p`. The script is effectively the following:

```
directoryStructure="$(zenity --title  "make directory structure" --text "Enter the directory structure (e.g. (\"foo/bar\"))" --entry)"
if [ ! -z "${directoryStructure}" ]; then
    mkdir -p "${directoryStructure}"
fi
```

How could I get this script to run for an empty directory? I know how to get it running only by accessing the context menu of an existing file. How can I get the script running when there are no files?

Answer (score 0):

You can't because of a bug reported **[here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1179744)**. If they fix the bug, you can do it. The importance of that bug is set to *Low*, so I wouldn't count on it for a moment, though.

In the mean time, you can go back to the parent directory and right-click on the empty directory you want to affect.

For example, if you want to use your script on `~/foo/bar/`, go to `~/foo/` and right-click on `bar`.